# Digital Camera Fingerprinting via Instagram and Snapchat

Tags: privacy, user-tracking, fingerprinting

I was going through one of the articles on camera fingerprinting that says that

> using most basic Instagram or Snapchat filters will not get rid of the
>   camera fingerprint. However, changing the resolution, which most
>   social media sites do, or blurring and then deblurring the photo will
>   scrub your picture of this camera fingerprint.

If these are true then is there any evidence or research work that explains these specific cases in a more elaborated way for a better understanding of the way the whole thing works?

Also, how can I defend my photographs on social media from being fingerprinted?

ref: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/2016/11/smartphones-camera-fingerprint-allows-anyone-track-videos-pictures-back/

Comment: I believe they are incorrect that changing resolution and such can get rid of fingerprints. Some camera fingerprints are very resilient, for example ones involving chromatic aberrations. If I recall correctly, you would not only have to reduce the resolution considerably (not just change, but reduce), as well as drastically decrease the color depth.

Comment: This might be better suited for [photo.se].

Comment: @Tom This is not about photography if u observe, it's about digital forensics.

Comment: I think it's about both and I'm pretty sure, there are a lot of people with a lot more knowledge about cameras on [photo.se]. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: The link you posted has a link to a research paper: http://www.ws.binghamton.edu/fridrich/Research/double.pdf (your first question), and the paper explains a method to remove fingerprints (potentially your 2nd question)

Comment: @schroeder I appreciate your effort but my question is more specific towards the filters used by Instagram and Snapchat as well as the sentence used on the blog which says "blurring and then deblurring the photo will scrub your picture of this camera fingerprint". I wish to validate this sentence.

Comment: the paper explains all that ...